# Amazon Redshift queries mysteriously dying

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Why is my Amazon Redshift query sometimes working, sometimes getting killed, and sometimes running out of memory?

This is a simple query:

```
dev=# EXPLAIN SELECT row_number, browser_cookie, "timestamp", request_path,
                     status,     outcome,         duration,   referrer
       FROM annotated_apache_logs
      WHERE date = '2015-09-15';
                                         QUERY PLAN                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 XN Seq Scan on annotated_apache_logs  (cost=0.00..114376.71 rows=9150137 width=207)
   Filter: (date = '2015-09-15'::date)
```

Pulling about 9 million rows:

```
dev=# SELECT count(*) FROM annotated_apache_logs WHERE date = '2015-09-15';
  count  
---------
 9150137
(1 row)
```

And choking:

```
dev=# SELECT row_number, browser_cookie, "timestamp", request_path,
             status,     outcome,        duration,    referrer
        FROM annotated_apache_logs
       WHERE date = '2015-09-15';
out of memory
```

Sometimes the sql says `Killed`. Sometimes it works. Sometimes I get `out of memory`. No idea why. The table looks like this (I've removed rows not in the above query):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS annotated_apache_logs (
  row_number           double precision,
  browser_cookie       character varying(240),
  timestamp            integer,
  request_path         character varying(2500),
  status               character varying(12),
  outcome              character varying(128),
  duration             integer,
  referrer             character varying(2500)
)
DISTKEY (date)
SORTKEY (browser_cookie);
```

And I've worked very hard to get all of those columns as small as I can to reduce memory usage. What do I look for now? If I read the `EXPLAIN` output correctly, this might return a couple of gigs of data. Not much data, no joins, nothing fancy. For a "petabyte scale data warehouse", that's trivial, so I'm assuming I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cursors to fetch the result set in chunks. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html

> If your client application uses an ODBC connection and your query creates a result set that is too large to fit in memory, you can stream the result set to your client application by using a cursor. When you use a cursor, the entire result set is materialized on the leader node, and then your client can fetch the results incrementally.

Edit:
Assuming that you want the entire result set rather than filtering using where/limit.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is actually running out of memory, check what is the concurrency for the WLM queue under which this query runs. Try to increase the available memory for this queue or reduce the concurrency, this will allow your query to have more memory.

P.S:
When it says "Petabyte scale", it does not mean it has petabyte of RAM for you. There are a lot of factors which decide how much memory your query is actually getting while execution,
What is the node type you are using? 
How many nodes? 
What other queries are running when you are running this query?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that it turns out to be a client limitation. Lots of work on tuning the queries and redefining the tables, only to realize that the client was causing the error messages, not Redshift.

Comment: Oh dear. Yeah, I thought about for a second while writing the answer but just didnt add it. By the way, what was the editor, and how did you fix it?

Comment: I meant "client" as in "client/server", not "editor." My AWS sandbox couldn't handle the amount of data Redshift was sending. I needed to boost my sandbox's memory or run the query on a beefier machine.